# How can I inset a SwiftUI list when the keyboard shows and the list is at the bottom like a chat app

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to inset the bottom of a list by the height of the keyboard when the keyboard shows and the list is scrolled to the bottom.  I know this question has been asked in different scenarios but I haven't found any proper solution yet.  This is specifically for a chat app and the simple code below demonstrates the problem:

```
@State var text: String = ""
@FocusState private var keyboardVisible: Bool

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Conversations")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        keyboardVisible = false
                    } label: {
                        Text("Hide Keyboard")
                    }
                }
            }
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                    .frame(height: 44)
                TextEditor(text: $text)
                    .frame(height: 32)
                    .focused($keyboardVisible)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you scroll to the end and tap in the textEditor, the text editor moves up with the keyboard as expected, but the list doesn't move the content up.  I wonder how I can achieve this and have it move up smoothly with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention trying it, but this is exactly what we have a `ScrollViewReader()` for. There is a bit of an issue using it in this case, that can be worked around. The issue is that `keyboardVisible` changes BEFORE the keyboard is fully up. If you scroll at that point, you will cut off the bottom of the `List` entries. So, we need to delay the reader with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)`. This causes enough delay that when the reader actually reads the position, the keyboard is at full height, and the scroll to the bottom does its job.

```
@State var text: String = ""
@FocusState private var keyboardVisible: Bool

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { scroll in
                List {
                    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: keyboardVisible, perform: { _ in
                    if keyboardVisible {
                        withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1)) {
                            scroll.scrollTo(100) // this would be your array.count - 1,
                                                 // but you hard coded your ForEach
                        }
                        // The scroll has to wait until the keyboard is fully up
                        // this causes it to wait just a bit.
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                            // this helps make it look deliberate and finished
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                                scroll.scrollTo(100) // this would be your array.count - 1,
                                // but you hard coded your ForEach
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .navigationTitle("Conversations")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button {
                            keyboardVisible = false
                        } label: {
                            Text("Hide Keyboard")
                        }
                    }
                }
                ZStack {
                    Color.red
                        .frame(height: 44)
                    TextEditor(text: $text)
                        .frame(height: 32)
                        .focused($keyboardVisible)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
I changed the code to scroll twice. The first starts the scroll immediately, and the second scrolls it after the keyboard is up to finish the job. It starts quickly and ends smoothly. I also left the comments in the code for the next person; you don't need them.

Comment: I have tried exactly this approach but because of that delay it is not a smooth transition to the keyboard.  I've used 0.22 seconds and 0.5 as you mention.

Comment: Also the duration you have in there makes no difference.  In fact if you use this approach it's much better to just listen for keyboardDidShow and no need to dispatch after or duration, just withAnimation.  Much better but still not good enough.

Comment: The transition is smooth, it is just delayed, as it has to be. When the keyboard starts to come on screen, it IS pushing the `List` up, but it is a specialized `Scrollview`, so the entries just go off the bottom. You can see this by hand scrolling the list with the keyboard up. Is it that you want it to start sooner?

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of words.  Your right and the animation is smooth.  It's just the delay  I don't like.  Previously with swift we could get the height of keyboard and apply inset to tableView with curve to match keyboard appearance.  I wanted to do the same.

Comment: just try it on WhatsApp and you'll see what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I deleted WhatsApp a long time ago. I don't like giving FaceBook my data. I made an edit you may like.

Comment: I've tried all those things many times and even more detailed doing several scrolls through the transition.  They all kind of work but not perfectly as it did prior to swiftUI and as with most chat apps.

Comment: It would be REALLY helpful when you ask a question that you go  through EVERYTHING you have tried and why you don't like it. Otherwise, you are wasting other's time trying to help you.

Comment: I’ve tried at least 30-40 different ways to achieve this. Should I list them all?   I want a proper solution if one exists.  Not hacks to kind of do something like what I want.  As stated in the question I want the list to move up smoothly with the keyboard.  I think anybody that has worked in a chat app knows exactly what I’m asking.  Or any that that hasn’t deleted WhatsApp.