# SwiftUI make scrollview item by item

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, scrollview

I need to create a list view with item like a square on a scrollview.

But I need to make the scroll only work to one item to another.

I could see the article allowing to set up this system on a HStack but I can't adapt it on a VStack

This article : https://levelup.gitconnected.com/snap-to-item-scrolling-debccdcbb22f

If someone has an idea to help me in this research?

I join an example of scrollview with the square :

```
struct ScrollingSnapped: View {

    var colors: [Color] = [.blue, .green, .red, .orange, .gray, .brown, .yellow, .purple]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(0..<colors.count) { index in
                    colors[index]
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollingSnapped_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollingSnapped()
    }
}
```

I tried to work with a `ScrollViewReader` that allows to `scrollTo`. It works when clicking on a button but I can't get it to work when scrolling :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollingSnapped: View {

    var colors: [Color] = [.blue, .green, .red, .orange, .gray, .brown, .yellow, .purple]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                Button {
                    proxy.scrollTo(4, anchor: .top)
                } label: {
                    Text("Scroll to square 5")
                }

                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 30) {
                    ForEach(0..<colors.count) { index in
                        colors[index]
                            .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .id(index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollingSnapped_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollingSnapped()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating it in a horizontal style then rotating it using .rotationeffect ?

Comment: Do you want the view to ONLY be able to move one item at a time? And, if so, how is the move triggered?

Comment: I just tried to use .rotationeffect and it works perfectly (I had to apply this rotation effect on the internal view so that the text is in the right direction but indeed it works correctly). I have now another problem but it has nothing to do with the initial subject. Inside my views, I have onTapGesture interactions that cancel the scroll possibility when I start to scroll by putting my cursor on the gestures.
But the rotationeffect solution works great!

Comment: @Yrb, Not totally, I just wish that via a scroll movement, the elements can't be displayed halfway. As in the article I linked, when scrolling, the elements can not be displayed only from a part, the center of the views is done in the center of the screen and when we start to scroll the next view comes to replace the view currently in place

Comment: So you want the scrollview to show a full cell at either the top or the bottom, regardless of where the user stops scrolling? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69466458/7129318).